# how do i join two different tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, phpmyadmin

This is table1:

```
    id  name    m1  m2  m3  total   itemno
    1   raj     10  10  10  30      1
    2   ram     60  60  60  180     1
    3   kumar   70  70  70  210     1
    4   kanna   50  50  50  150     1
    5   vivek   64  64  91  200     1
     5  vivek   90  90  90  270     2
```

This is table2:

```
    id  name          mark1     mark2   mark3   itemno
    101 vivek            78     78       78     1
    102 vivekkanna       89     88       78     1
    103 rajagopalan      97     90       98     1
    104 kumar            69     54       56     1
    101 vivek            90     90       90     2
```

I want to join these two tables like this into a result set that looks like this:

```
    id  name    m1  m2  m3  total mark1     mark2   mark3 item no
    1   raj     10  10  10  30     0         0       0     1 
    2   ram     60  60  60  180    0         0       0     1
    3   kumar   70  70  70  210    69       54      56     1
    4   kanna   50  50  50  150    0         0       0     1
    5   vivek   64  64  91  200    78       78      78     1
    5   vivek   90  90  90  270    90       90      90     2
```

Comment: Your table design is suspect. How do you differentiate between the 2 `Vivek`s?

Comment: why not store all off the data in one table ? still if you want to store it separately in two table then store table1_id in table2

Comment: this is example tables

Comment: Is there any relationship present between the tables?

Comment: You can store `table1` colum `id` in `table2`  for `join` between two table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you want a regular LEFT JOIN, returning a default value if the row in table2 does not exist;

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.m1, t1.m2, t1.m3, 
       COALESCE(t2.mark1, 0)  mark1, COALESCE(t2.mark2, 0)  mark2, t1.itemno
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.itemno = t2.itemno
ORDER BY t1.id, t1.itemno
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5aa2c/2)

We use a LEFT JOIN to get the default NULL value for all table2 fields that don't match with a row in table1, then COALESCE to turn them into 0 instead.